# creating enemies and collision detect

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm trying to make a shooting game in which enemies fall down randomly and the player will shoot at it. but i'm having troubles with creating the enemies and hitTestObject isn't working when the missile and enemy collides. the bullet and enemy just doesn't disappear. can anyone help me with this? And the enemy isn't falling at all. it just kept poping on the same place. It's a homework and it's gonna be due soon. i can't proceed if i can't get this done. really desperate here.

enemy.as file:

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip{
        var Enemy_One;



        public function Enemy(){
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onEnemyAdded);
        }

        private function onEnemyAdded (event:Event) {
            Enemy_One = MovieClip(this);

            addEventListener.(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
        }

        private function enemyLoop (event:Event) {

            for (var i:int = 0;i<Enemy_One.myMissile.numChildren; i++) {
                var MissileTarget:MovieClip = Enemy_One.myMissile.getChildAt(i);
                if (hitTestObject(MissileTarget)){
                    Enemy_One.myMissile.getChildAt(i).removeListener();
                    Enemy_One.myMissile.removeChild(MissileTarget);


                    removeEventListener.(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
                    Enemy_One.removeChild(this);
                }

            this.y+= 2;
            }
        }

        public function removeListeners():void{
            removeEventListener.(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
        }

    }
```

missile as.file:

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Missile extends MovieClip{
        public var speed:int = 30;
        var radianAngle:Number;
        var xVelocity:Number;
        var yVelocity:Number;

        public function Missile(){
             addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onMissileAdded);
         }

        private function onMissileAdded (event:Event):void {
            // execute these when Missile is added to stage
            radianAngle = this.rotation*(Math.PI/180);
            yVelocity = Math.sin(radianAngle)*speed;
            xVelocity = Math.cos(radianAngle)*speed;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            }

        private function update (event:Event):void {
            // update Missile every frame
            // Missile moves itself on the stage and remove itself when it is off the stage
            if (this.x<0 || this.x>stage.stageWidth || this.y<0 || this.y>stage.stageHeight) {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
                parent.removeChild(this);

            }
            this.x+= xVelocity;
            this.y+= yVelocity;
        }

        public function removeListeners ():void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }
    }
```

main timeline as:

```
//Shooting Missile Setup//


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doShoot);
function doShoot (e:MouseEvent):void {
    var radianAngle = Math.atan2(mouseY-myShooter.y,mouseX-myShooter.x);
    var myMissile:MovieClip = new Missile();
    myMissile.x = myShooter.x;
    myMissile.y = myShooter.y;
    myMissile.rotation = radianAngle*180/Math.PI;
    addChild(myMissile);
    myShooter.gotoAndPlay("blast");

}

//**Refer to external as. file (Missile)**
//Shooting Missile Setup//


//Enemy Setup//

var myMissile:MovieClip = new Missile();
var enemyTimer:Timer = new Timer (1000);
enemyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER ,onStart);
enemyTimer.start();

function onStart (e:Event){

    var myEnemy1:MovieClip = new Enemy1();
    myEnemy1.y+=200;
    myEnemy1.x = Math.random()*600;
    addChild(myEnemy1);

}
```

}

Comment: You've got a typo in your `Enemy` class: ` addEventListener.(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);`

Comment: well it still didn't work after i change the typo. so do u know what's wrong? my brain is stuck

Comment: There are actually quite a few things wrong with the code above. By fixing they typo, this should actually enable the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` call to `enemyLoop`. At that point, I'd imagine you'd get an error when you attempt to access `Enemy_One.myMissile` -- a property that doesn't appear to exist in your `Enemy` class. I would suggest looking up a full tutorial on object-oriented programming and then another one on implementing collision detection in AS3.